# <HTML> tag not fitting to the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css

In my webpage the video background does not fit to the screen on mobile (it fits in landscape).

This is the video tag.

```
<video
    autoPlay
    loop
    muted
    playsInline
    className='absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 object-cover z-0 overflow-hidden'
  >
```

And this is the global css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: SF Pro Display, SF Pro Icons, Helvetica, Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height:  1.1;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1BJf.png)

This is my first post so please tell me if I need to add anything.

Comment: is it overflowing and causing a side-scroll, or is the div too small?

Comment: @RandomCoder it is causing a side scroll

Comment: try `body {overflow: hidden}` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

solved the issue.

Thanks to @RandomCoder

Answer (score 0):

try this in your CSS code:

```
video{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: sadly this did not help the side-scrolling issue

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to let me see how it looks like? @OlleJernström

Comment: There is a link in the post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1BJf.png) @Igli